# array_sum result is negative

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so

```
array (size=5107)
  0 => int 421
  1 => int 996
  2 => int 1555
  3 => int 399
  4 => int 57914
  5 => int 57245
  6 => int 7176
  7 => int 7166
  8 => int 5987
```

This array is being generated by pulling some timestamps from a database, comparing them and then getting the difference in seconds like so;

```
$start_date = new DateTime($startdate);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($closedate));

$diff = strtotime($closedate) - strtotime($startdate);
```

I then want to get the average of the array, but whenever I do a `array_sum($array);` the result is always negative and I'm not sure why. What am I misunderstanding here?

If I change

```
$diff = strtotime($closedate) - strtotime($startdate);
```

To

```
$diff = strtotime($startdate) - strtotime($closedate);
```

The `array_sum($array);` results in a positive value but all the array values are negative but all the results are the same.

Comment: Could it be an integer overflow by any chance?! That'd be weird. Or are there actual negative numbers in your array?

Comment: @deceze There are no negative numbers in the array, but there are 5107 results in it.

Comment: @deceze In PHP, overflow causes it to convert to floating point, not wrap around.

Comment: Can you boil it down to a concrete example that we can confirm ourselves?

Comment: I presume you've written a bit of code to traverse the array checking for negative values?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the absolute value:

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($closedate) - strtotime($startdate));
```

Comment: @Michael N Obviously because now a diff is always positive

Comment: `abs` is a math term refers to absolute value `|-x|=x`

Comment: I would not recommend this solution. It will only change anything if  startdate is later than closedate. In this case something else is wrong, and using abs() will give you a wrong but positive (so not obviously wrong) result.

Comment: @MichaelN There must have been some negative values in your array. Apparently some of your close date are before the corresponding start date, you should figure out why that's happening and fix it.